# Access Control not Using Database

Tags: linux, apache, .htaccess

I have an application installed say at http://gwmubiru.com/login.php.

I want to send this as demo to different potential customers. I want to be able to grant and /or deny access to customers. I don't want to setup each customer as a user in the database since my demos have more than one user type I want to demo.

Is there a way to control access may be using Apache, htaccess or even linux?

Answer (score 1):

You can use http Authentication.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/howto/auth.html

You create several users/passwords and give one to each of your clients. After that you remove their access.

Answer (score 0):

You're right, you've got options:

From Apache, probably the easiest mechanism is [mod_authz_host](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authz_host.html#allow):

```
Allow from apache.org
Allow from .net example.edu
```

It works in both `<directory>` and `htaccess` files, so it might be easiest.

If you want to limit access to your entire webserver, you can certainly add firewall rules that will allow only your clients to access it. This might be a little anti-social, but if you'd really like only your clients and potential clients to ever see the demo system, firewalling can do that.

The [`ufw`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UFW) tool can make adding firewall rules pretty easy; you might wish to try it if you're very new to firewalling.

```
sudo ufw allow from 192.168.0.4 to any port 80
```

If you want to learn more about [IPTables](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/IptablesHowTo), then you might do better just skipping past `ufw`. It's been a while since I've configured IPTables (and I'm afraid I'll never know it as well as [OpenBSD's `pf`](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=pf&sektion=4&manpath=OpenBSD+4.8) firewall). Don't forget to leave yourself an `ssh` path back to your server, and consider using the [`iptables-apply`](http://man.he.net/man8/iptables-apply) script to test changes on remote systems. (We've all locked ourselves out of our servers at some point, just don't make a habit of it.)